# What are the differences between Pathfinder, and Pathfinder 2e playtest v1.6?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, edition-comparison, pathfinder-2e-playtest

Of course, by "Pathfinder 2e" I mean the new version of Pathfinder that has currently been released by Paizo for playtesting; **Version 1.6**. The type of answer I would prefer is an unordered list which lists the primary differences between the two RPG systems from a systemic level. Such as differences in combat rules, class abilities, feat changes, spell changes, etc.

For more information about expected formatting, please check the top answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1/differences-between-dd-3-5-and-pathfinder).

Play experience with Pathfinder 2e isn't required, I only need a comparison between the system and its mechanics from a technical standpoint. When information changes or becomes available for the Pathfinder 2e playtest, I'll make a new question with a bounty for an update on the mechanics changes when the completed, full version of Pathfinder 2e releases.

Comment: Related: [Does Pathfinder 2e Playtest fix the “linear fighters, quadratic wizards” problem?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131069/does-pathfinder-2e-playtest-fix-the-linear-fighters-quadratic-wizards-problem)

Comment: Im voting to close because the playtest is changing every 2 weeks, sometimes drastically (as seen on 1.6). This answer will be outdated quickly and wont be useful to future readers. However, you may freely contact me if interested on a review on these changes.

Comment: @ShadowKras it's notable that 1.6 is supposed to be the last of the biweekly updates. I still agree with the "too broad" since there are a ton of differences between the versions (and the differences change based on what extra books you use, e.g. APG changes a lot). But changes moving forward probably won't be on the 2-week interval like clockwork they have been.